# Change a pseudo-code such that we get rid of a loop

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have the following pseudo-code:

```
read n
p <- 1;
m <- 0;
k <- 0;
while ( n != 0 )
    read x
    for ( i <- 1, k )
        x <- [x / 10]

    if ( x != 0 )
        c <- x % 10
    else
        c <- n % 10

    m <- c * p + m
    n <- [n / 10]
    p <- p * 10
    k <- k + 1
write m
```

and I have to transform this code such that we have just 1 loop. I went over examples over and over again and I don't see what I should do. I think we need that first `while` loop so I kept trying to get rid of that `for` loop function but I don't see how I could get the same behavior with just one loop.

(Excuse the terrible style of pseudo-code)

Comment: I recommend more meaningful variable names.  Overall what is code trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the

```
for ( i <- 1, k )
    x <- [x / 10]
```

loop, it divides `x` by `10 ** k`, and

```
x <- [x / 10**k]
```

accomplishes exactly what the loop does. If you have a feeling that raising to a power is a loop in disguise, consider

```
power_of_ten = 1
while ( n != 0 )
    read x
    x <- [x / power_of_ten]
    ....
    power_of_ten <- power_of_ten * 10
```

Comment: And I can use the variable 'p' exactly for that! I didn't notice that's why they included that variable.